# Moving files, some end up in recycle bin

Tags: sharepoint-online

When moving files from one site to another in SharePoint Online. I noticed that some of them end up in the recycle bin. Is it default behaviour that the file ends up in the recycle bin on the site where you moved the file from?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How you are moved the files, have you in both enabled versioning, is the setup exactly the same?

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška yes, it is set up in exactly the same way.

Comment: and how way you are moving these files? with some program? script?

Answer (score 0):

How did you move the file from one site to another site?

It is not the normal behavior that files are moved in the recycle bin.

You could restore the files from the recycle bin and move again to check if it can work.

Comment: I moved the files by using the SharePoint move-to functionality.